# Why use nodemon start express server can't show react components?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I have a express app, I excute `npm run bundle` to build bundle.js and put the file in views directory. The issue is it can't show react components when I excute `npm start`, but work correctly when I open the index.html just by browser, how can I start express server with render react components correctly and what happened here?

## app.js

```
"use strict"
import path from 'path'
import express from 'express'
// routes
const app = express()
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views/index.html'))
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})

export default app
```

## views/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

## react/index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

class HelloMessage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
}

export default HelloMessage

ReactDOM.render(<HelloMessage name="Tsao" />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

## package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "nyc mocha",
    "start": "nodemon app.js --exec babel-node",
    "coverage": "nyc report --reporter=text-lcov | coveralls",
    "bundle": "webpack",
    "build": "babel server --out-dir build && webpack",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --devtool eval --progress --colors --content-base views"
  }
```

## webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './react/index.js',
  ],
  output: {
    path: `${__dirname}/views`,
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['es2015','stage-3','react']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
};
```

Comment: Post your webpack config

Comment: I have edit it and add webpack config